# How to print value pointed by register

Tags: gdb, reverse-engineering, cpu-registers

I am trying to learn asembly and reverse and whene i tryed to debug a simple chall i wanted to see my registers in gdb with info registers
Rax 0x7fffffdd90 
Now inwant to know where rax. Is pointîg to ,( inprentrd rax now i want to print [rax] ) 
Or is it possible to set a pointed value in register 
Inteed of doing set $eax = $rax 
I want to do somthing like set $eax = [$rax]

Thanx for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Rax 0x7fffffdd90 
>   Now inwant to know where rax. Is pointîg to

You *already* know that: it points to (stack) memory location at address `0x7fffffdd90`.

> i want to print [rax]

```
 x/gx $rax
```

or

```
 print *(int**)$rax
```

> I want to do somthing like set $eax = [$rax]

```
set $rax = *(int**)$rax
```